# Y Interval in chart control not properly adjusted

Tags: charts, plot, axis, intervals, microsoft-chart-controls

I'm plotting integer data series dynamically on a chart control. The range of the values of the series can vary a lot, f.e. y ranging from 0-100 and x ranging from 1-6000.
I'm using chart1.ChartAreas[chartName].RecalculateAxesScale() and I do not get my y axis properly adjusted.
For series with low y-values with f.e. y's between 0-3 the y-Axis is set to a numerical scale with interval [0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5]. But I only want the interval to be [0,1,2,3].
When I set AxisY.Interval=1 then in the series with values ranging from 0-100 every y tick gets plotted.

How can I set my y-Axis to use auto interval adjustment, but with only integer ticks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could handle the `Customize` event of Chart control. Since you haven't posted any code showing what you have done, here is some pseudo code

```
private void chart1_Customize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // if Y axis range is small =>  set Y axis interval 
    // else if Y axis range is ..... => set diff Y axis interval
}
```

Comment: this seems to be a good solution. I'm now using: `if (chart1.Series["Series1"].Points.FindMaxByValue("Y1").YValues[0] < 10)
                    {
                        chartArea.AxisY.Interval = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        chartArea.AxisY.Interval = Double.NaN;
                    }` and it works fine